# Rails - invalid CSRF while talking to api

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an api setup in my rails application, and after creating my first form and trying to post something I encountered this error:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken  - ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken:
```

I have read plenty of posts that recommended things like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    })
```

or passing `form_authenticity_token` directly to my javascript (as this is a remote form), but nothing works. Still the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: It's usually better practice to disable CSRF for API, and use another authentication to protect.

Comment: What would you suggest, James Chen?

Comment: If you have a base API controller, you could add this to that API base controller: `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token`. Using which authentication method for the API is a case to case thing and you should search and find one suitable for your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Authenticating to an API should be done usually with a key and secret instead.

Comment: Am I supposed to use it inside my ApplicationController, or inside my ApiControllers?

Comment: I will actually stick to it. Do you have any articles/ tuts that you can recommend how to use key and secret to authenticate api?